# HC-05 Bluetooth Module CircuitMaker

Tags: pcb, design, bluetooth, footprint, hc-05

I am new to PCB design, and I am designing a circuit with a HC-05 Bluetooth module. I'm using Altium CircuitMaker and there are no symbols or models in there for a HC-05 Bluetooth module. Does anyone know where I can find a symbol/model (or I think they are called footprints maybe?) that I can put into CircuitMaker?

(I am thinking of using an HC-05 module something like [this one](https://core-electronics.com.au/bluetooth-module-hc-05.html).)

Comment: General tip if you are just getting into PCB design, don't spend too much time searching for already made footprints or symbols. Learn to draw them yourself from information found in the datasheet. It's really not very difficult and you will have to do it sooner or later.

Comment: Are you planning on using an HC-05 module with header pins already mounted to it, or the smaller module type with castellated (half) pads at the module edges? Can you add a link to the exact HC-05 part you plan on using?

Comment: @Nedd I am thinking of using one with header pins already attached. Something like this one https://core-electronics.com.au/bluetooth-module-hc-05.html

Answer (score 1):

If using the [module that you linked to](https://core-electronics.com.au/bluetooth-module-hc-05.html) with a male 6-pin header you might get away with just placing a matching female header connector onto your PCB design. You may need to manually allow for any extra clearance around the connector, (you could add a larger component keep-out zone around it). To ensure correct installation you might at least want to clearly show the pin 1 location. You could also manually add extra silk-screen lines that better show the module's correct physical orientation.

During assembly it would be up to you if you actually place a female connector at that position (then later insert the module), or if you will ultimately solder the module pins directly into your PCB.

Yet another option would be to replace the right angle header pins on the module with straight header pins, (on the bottom side). This would allow the module to sit flat (or parallel) to main PCB surface. Of course that orientation may require more board space on your design. However, with careful planning you may be able to mount the module elevated enough so that smaller components could be mounted below it. Such mounting may also require a raised stand-off placed at the opposite side of the module to keep it level to the main board.